# What is the common diet of food-related IBS patients? Besides most patients being lactose intolerant, what other intolerances do they face?

Tags: microbiology, food, nutrition

I am currently writing a paper on irritable bowel syndrome, and I was wondering what the common diet of a patient with food-related IBS consists of. I've already begun discussing the pathogenesis of the disorder, but I want to start making a connection between food and IBS. I understand that most patients tend to be lactose intolerant, but I am also interested to see if there are any other common intolerances associated with IBS.

Answer (score 2):

IBS stands for **[Irritable Bowel Syndrome](https://bestpractice.bmj.com/topics/en-gb/122)**. The IBS symptoms include belly pain, diarrhea, bloating and constipation. Different persons have an intolerance to different food items. You can know what's causing trouble in you by taking a test at http://intolerancelab.co.uk/intolerance-2.

**The most common diets that you can prefer to get rid of IBS symptoms are:**

1. High Fiber Diets can help prevent constipation.
2. For some people, high fiber diet is intolerant. They should switch to a low fiber diet.
3. You should prefer a gluten-free diet.
4. Have a low-fat diet and get rid of a number of health problems.

**Some food items that can cause [food intolerance](https://solvingtheibspuzzle.com/food-intolerance/) are:**

1. Dairy products
2. Soy products
3. Fructose
4. Wheat
5. Gluten

Answer (score 1):

Fermentable carbohydrates may cause problems in some IBS patients. Recent work suggests that restricting these foods may improve the symptoms in some patients.

http://www.nature.com/nrgastro/journal/v11/n4/abs/nrgastro.2013.259.html

More information can be found by looking for the FODMAP diet.

Comment: This is from a recent abstract relating to FODMAPS:  Food intolerance in irritable bowel syndrome (IBS) is increasingly being recognized, with patients convinced that diet plays a role in symptom induction. Evidence is building to implicate fermentable oligosaccharides, disaccharides, monosaccharides and polyols (FODMAPs) in the onset of abdominal pain, bloating, wind and altered bowel habit through their fermentation and osmotic effects. Source: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3388522/

Comment: The question was originally about food tolerance, but was meant to question intolerance to the food, hence the comment. I think the OP essentially worded the question incorrectly, which has now been corrected. Hence I shall remove the comment shortly.